# How to make Joda work with String.format method (i.e. java.util.Formatter class)?

Tags: java, formatting, jodatime

Is it possible to make an `org.joda.time.LocalDate.LocalDate` object work seamlessly with `String.format`?  Here is a simple test case to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
public class JodaTests {

    @Test
    public void testLocalDateStringFormat() {
        final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JodaTests.class);
        //works, prints: 2012-06-01
        logger.info(String.format("%s", new LocalDate()));
        //works, prints: 06/01/2012
        logger.info(String.format("%1$tm/%1$td/%1$tY", new LocalDate().toDate()));
        //throws java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: m != org.joda.time.LocalDate
        logger.info(String.format("%1$tm/%1$td/%1$tY", new LocalDate()));
    }

}
```

So clearly, I can call the `toDate` method to convert the `LocalDate` to a `java.util.Date`, which then works fine with [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).  But is there a way to configure Joda and/or the JDK somehow to make the 3rd line I have there (the one that throws the exception) work?  I have tried web searches, and also searched a bit through the 
Joda API but didn't see any obvious answer.

**Clarification**: I know about Joda's built-in formatting capabilities (via `DateTimeFormat`) but I specifically need to format a `LocalDate` with `String.format` due to some library code I'm using.

It looks like there is some limited capability to do this by implementing the `Formattable` interface in your custom type as described in [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_printf_with_customized_formattable).  Unfortunately, `LocalDate` is a `final` class so I can't (easily) extend it to implement the interface.  I guess a wrapper class is the only way to go.  Or, of course, by using `%d` format strings then fetching each individual field (i.e. `LocalDate.getYear`), which isn't desirable in my case.

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't just use JODA's formatting code to get a `String` that you can then pass in to `String.format`.

Comment: That will probably be what I end up doing.  I'm using Spring Batch, which has built-in support for extracting fields from an output object (in my case, a complex class with many fields of varying types, including `LocalDate`s) and writing those values to a flat file with minimal configuration.  However, it doesn't seem to work too well in practice (not only for this, but also formatting - in a consistent way - BigDecimals which may or may not be `null`).  So I will probably just have to accumulate a bunch of `String`s and not use the Spring Batch formatted aggregator functionality.

Answer (score 4):

do you need to use string formatter, if you just need a string you can do this (or use antoher format/pattern) :

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy").print(new LocaDate());
```

Comment: I know about `DateTimeFormat` but I'd like this to work specifically with `String.format` because some library code I'm using calls that.  If I could make it work this way, I could avoid writing a bunch of extra code just to use Joda's built-in formatting capabilities.

Comment: That's just not possible; `Formatter` knows nothing about JODA whatsoever.  If you want to use JODA dates within bigger strings constructed with `Formatter`, just do something like `String.format("Date: %s%n", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy").print(new LocalDate()))`.